# Forbid gradle clean up some folders

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, build.gradle

I have the next problem. To make my app workable on Google Play I have to put **folder called "libs" with some libraries into "build" folder** (*/app/build/*) but gradle clean this directory before making project. So, errors are caused. Please, say me what I have to do to forbid gradle clean this path **/app/build/**. Write code I need please :)

Project structure:
[image: project structure]

Comment: You should not be modifying the `build/` folder manually. Whatever problem you are trying to solve this way should be solved in some other way. What problem are you trying to solve, and why do you think that this is the right way to solve it?

Comment: @CommonsWare, when I upload my app to Google Play without "libs" in "build" folder, Google Play says "app isn't compatible with any android device". I found out that that problem was caused by these two libs - "commons-io-2.4.jar" and "gson-2.8.0.jar". But if I put them by this path /app/build/ - my app works/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Create `app/libs/`, if that directory does not already exist

Step #2: Put those JARs in `app/libs/`

Step #3: Add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` to the `dependencies` closure of your `app/build.gradle` file, if it is not already in there

Step #4: Stop messing with `app/build/`

Step #5: Ship your app